# remove zero values of an array in numba cuda

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I have a long array

```
arr = np.array([1,1,2,2,3,3,0,0,2,2])
```

I would like to remove all zero values of this array in numba cuda since the real array is very large and numpy is very slow.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: This algorithm is classically referred to as "stream compaction" in the GPGPU literature, and you would need to write your own implementation in the Numba CUDA  python dialect. Note that while there are a number of extremely efficient CUDA implementations available, some of them rely on CUDA features which are currently not supported by the Numba compiler

Comment: do you have any suggested algorithms?

Comment: A simple stream compaction operation can be written as a prefix sum (to generate copy indices) followed by an indexed copy.  The prefix sum treats any non-zero input value as a 1 to generate a copy-to index in the output array. The prefix sum is the harder part of this.    `cupy` has a prefix sum [here](http://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.cumsum.html) and it should be interoperable with numba and numpy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, the algorithm that you are looking for is called **Stream Compaction**. Since the said algorithm is not available out-of-the-box in `numba`, so it has to be implemented by hand. 
Basically, the process is as follows:

1. Create binary mask of input values to identify non-zero values.
2. Calculate prefix sum of the mask
3. For each non-zero value, copy it to the index specified by the output of prefix sum at the corresponding index of the value.

For step 3 explanation, consider the following example:

Lets say there is a non-zero value at index number 5 of the input array. We pick the value at index number 5 of the prefix sum array (lets say that value was 3). Use this value as the output index. It means that element at index number 5 of the input will go to index number 3 in the final output.

Calculation of prefix sum is the difficult part in this whole process. I took the liberty of porting the C++ version of prefix sum algorithm (adapted from the GPU Gems 3 book) to `numba`. If we implement prefix sum ourselves, we can merge step 1 and 2 into a single CUDA kernel.

Following is a complete working example of `numba` based stream compaction with the provided use case.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import cuda, int32

BLOCK_SIZE = 8

#CUDA kernel to calculate prefix sum of each block of input array
@cuda.jit('void(int32[:], int32[:], int32[:], int32)')
def prefix_sum_nzmask_block(a, b, s, length):
    ab = cuda.shared.array(shape=(BLOCK_SIZE), dtype=int32)

    tid = cuda.blockIdx.x * cuda.blockDim.x + cuda.threadIdx.x;

    if tid < length:
        ab[cuda.threadIdx.x] = int32(a[tid] != 0); #Load mask of input data into shared memory

    i = 1
    while i<=cuda.threadIdx.x:
        cuda.syncthreads() #Total number of cuda.synchthread calls = log2(BLOCK_SIZE).
        ab[cuda.threadIdx.x] += ab[cuda.threadIdx.x - i] #Perform scan on shared memory
        i *= 2

    b[tid] = ab[cuda.threadIdx.x]; #Write scanned blocks to global memory

    if(cuda.threadIdx.x == cuda.blockDim.x-1):  #Last thread of block
        s[cuda.blockIdx.x] = ab[cuda.threadIdx.x]; #Write last element of shared memory into global memory



#CUDA kernel to merge the prefix sums of individual blocks
@cuda.jit('void(int32[:], int32[:], int32)')
def prefix_sum_merge_blocks(b, s, length):
    tid = (cuda.blockIdx.x + 1) * cuda.blockDim.x + cuda.threadIdx.x; #Skip first block

    if tid<length:
        i = 0
        while i<=cuda.blockIdx.x:
            b[tid] += s[i] #Accumulate last elements of all previous blocks
            i += 1


#CUDA kernel to copy non-zero entries to the correct index of the output array
@cuda.jit('void(int32[:], int32[:], int32[:], int32)')
def map_non_zeros(a, prefix_sum, nz, length):
    tid = cuda.blockIdx.x * cuda.blockDim.x + cuda.threadIdx.x;

    if tid < length:
        input_value = a[tid]
        if input_value != 0:
            index = prefix_sum[tid] #The correct output index is the value at current index of prefix sum array
            nz[index-1] = input_value



#Apply stream compaction algorithm to get only the non-zero entries from the input array
def get_non_zeros(a):   
    length = a.shape[0]
    block = BLOCK_SIZE
    grid = int((length + block - 1)/block)

    #Create auxiliary array to hold the sum of each block
    block_sum = cuda.device_array(shape=(grid), dtype=np.int32)

    #Copy input array from host to device
    ad = cuda.to_device(a)

    #Create prefix sum output array
    bd = cuda.device_array_like(ad)

    #Perform partial scan of each block. Store block sum in auxillary array named block_sum.
    prefix_sum_nzmask_block[grid, block](ad, bd, block_sum, length)

    #Add block sum to the output
    prefix_sum_merge_blocks[grid, block](bd,block_sum,length);

    #The last element of prefix sum contains the total number of non-zero elements
    non_zero_count = int(bd[bd.shape[0]-1])

    #Create device output array to hold ONLY the non-zero entries
    non_zeros = cuda.device_array(shape=(non_zero_count), dtype=np.int32)

    #Copy ONLY the non-zero entries
    map_non_zeros[grid, block](a, bd, non_zeros, length)

    #Return to host
    return non_zeros.copy_to_host()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    arr = np.array([1,1,2,2,3,3,0,0,2,2], dtype=np.int32)

    nz = get_non_zeros(arr)

    print(nz)
```

**Tested with the following environment:**

Python 3.6.7 in virtual environment

CUDA 10.0.130

NVIDIA Driver 410.48

numba 0.42

Ubuntu 18.04

**Disclaimer:** The code is for demo purpose only and has not been profiled/tested rigorously for performance measurements.

Comment: your first `syncthreads()` is inside conditional code that does not evaluate uniformly across the block.

Comment: there is also a shared memory race condition in this line: `ab[cuda.threadIdx.x] += ab[cuda.threadIdx.x - i]`

Answer (score 0):

There were some issues with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54297125/1695960) and I [happened to take a closer look](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/sparse-matrix-manipulation/267671), so I will share my findings here as well.

1. As already mentioned via comments, the other answer has a shared memory race condition (detectable by `cuda-memcheck` or `compute-sanitizer`).
2. As already mentioned via comments, the other answer has illegal usage of `cuda.syncthreads()` (used in conditional code where the condition does not always evaluate the same across a warp).
3. The other answer has a defect in this line:

   ```
   b[tid] = ab[cuda.threadIdx.x]; #Write scanned blocks to global memory
   ```

   which is not properly conditioned via `if tid < length:`, so, for some input configurations, can perform illegal writes to global space.
4. In the other answer, the `prefix_sum_nzmask_block` kernel is reasonably well designed, but the `prefix_sum_merge_blocks` kernel is not, especially for larger test cases, where it will dominate execution time.

The following code has those issues addressed.  The first 3 items are relatively trivial to fix.  To fix the 4th item, I recast the algorithm to perform a full, proper prefix sum, using a recursive method.  Here is an example, much of it lifted from the other answer:

```
$ cat t71.py
import numpy as np
from numba import cuda, int32

BSP2 = 9  # possible values are integers from 1`to 10, 9 corresponds to 512 threads per block (2^9)
BLOCK_SIZE = 2**BSP2

#CUDA kernel to calculate prefix sum of each block of input array
#@cuda.jit('void(int32[:], int32[:], int32[:], int32, int32)')
@cuda.jit
def prefix_sum_nzmask_block(a, b, s, nzm, length):
    ab = cuda.shared.array(shape=(BLOCK_SIZE), dtype=int32)

    tid = cuda.blockIdx.x * cuda.blockDim.x + cuda.threadIdx.x;
    ab[cuda.threadIdx.x] = 0
    if tid < length:
        if nzm == 1:
            ab[cuda.threadIdx.x] = int32(a[tid] != 0); #Load mask of input data into shared memory
        else:
            ab[cuda.threadIdx.x] = int32(a[tid]); #Load input data into shared memory
    for j in range(0,BSP2):
        i = 2**j
        cuda.syncthreads()
        if i <= cuda.threadIdx.x:
            temp = ab[cuda.threadIdx.x]
            temp += ab[cuda.threadIdx.x - i] #Perform scan on shared memory
        cuda.syncthreads()
        if i <= cuda.threadIdx.x:
            ab[cuda.threadIdx.x] = temp
    if tid < length:
        b[tid] = ab[cuda.threadIdx.x]; #Write scanned blocks to global memory

    if(cuda.threadIdx.x == cuda.blockDim.x-1):  #Last thread of block
        s[cuda.blockIdx.x] = ab[cuda.threadIdx.x]; #Write last element of shared memory into global memory

#CUDA kernel to merge the prefix sums of individual blocks
@cuda.jit('void(int32[:], int32[:], int32)')
def pref_sum_update(b, s, length):
    tid = (cuda.blockIdx.x + 1) * cuda.blockDim.x + cuda.threadIdx.x; #Skip first block
    if tid<length:
        b[tid] += s[cuda.blockIdx.x] #Accumulate last elements of all previous blocks

#CUDA kernel to copy non-zero entries to the correct index of the output array
@cuda.jit('void(int32[:], int32[:], int32[:], int32)')
def map_non_zeros(a, prefix_sum, nz, length):
    tid = cuda.blockIdx.x * cuda.blockDim.x + cuda.threadIdx.x;

    if tid < length:
        input_value = a[tid]
        if input_value != 0:
            index = prefix_sum[tid] #The correct output index is the value at current index of prefix sum array
            nz[index-1] = input_value

#Recursive prefix sum (inclusive scan)
#a and asum should already be in device memory, nzm determines whether first step is masking values (nzm = 1) or not
def pref_sum(a, asum, nzm):
    block = BLOCK_SIZE
    length = a.shape[0]
    grid = int((length + block -1)/block)
    #Create auxiliary array to hold the sum of each block
    bs = cuda.device_array(shape=(grid), dtype=np.int32)

    #Perform partial scan of each block. Store block sum in auxillary array.
    prefix_sum_nzmask_block[grid, block](a, asum, bs, nzm, length)
    if grid > 1:
        bssum = cuda.device_array(shape=(grid), dtype=np.int32)
        pref_sum(bs, bssum, 0) #recursively build complete prefix sum
        pref_sum_update[grid-1, block](asum, bssum, length)

#Apply stream compaction algorithm to get only the non-zero entries from the input array
def get_non_zeros(a):
    #Copy input array from host to device
    ad = cuda.to_device(a)

    #Create prefix sum output array
    bd = cuda.device_array_like(ad)

    #Perform full prefix sum
    pref_sum(ad, bd, int(1))

    #The last element of prefix sum contains the total number of non-zero elements
    non_zero_count = int(bd[bd.shape[0]-1])
    #Create device output array to hold ONLY the non-zero entries
    non_zeros = cuda.device_array(shape=(non_zero_count), dtype=np.int32)

    #Copy ONLY the non-zero entries
    block = BLOCK_SIZE
    length = a.shape[0]
    grid = int((length + block -1)/block)
    map_non_zeros[grid, block](ad, bd, non_zeros, length)

    #Return to host
    return non_zeros.copy_to_host()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr_size = 5000000
    arr = np.zeros(arr_size, dtype=np.int32)
    for i in range(32,arr_size, 3):
        arr[i] = i
    print(arr_size)
    nz = get_non_zeros(arr)

    print(nz)
$ cuda-memcheck python t71.py
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
5000000
[     32      35      38 ..., 4999991 4999994 4999997]
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```